# Setting Timer to alternate between two intervals for random number generation

Tags: c#

I want to display two different randomly generated numbers in two different text boxes. The numbers in the text boxes change every second. I am invoking System.Random to create the random numbers:

```
    private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(min, max);
    }
```

The issue I am running into is that System.Random generates numbers based upon the system time, so the text boxes generate two identical random numbers every second of the tick. I have tried to approach this problem by staggering generation of the numbers by 20 ms. I have done this by creating two different timers (one for each text box) that alternate  between 980 and 1020 ms intervals:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int xgpscoord;

        timer1.Interval = 980;
        xgpscoord = RandomNumber(10000, 90000);
        textBoxGPSx.Text = xgpscoord.ToString();
        timer1.Interval = 1020;


    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int ygpscoord;

        timer2.Interval = 1020;
        ygpscoord = RandomNumber(10000, 90000);
        textBoxGPSy.Text = ygpscoord.ToString();
        timer2.Interval = 980;


    }
```

However, this does not synchronize the timers. I want them to tick every 1000 ms simultaneously. I think (correct me if I am wrong) that I am setting the intervals in the wrong places and only one of the two intervals that I set in each timer is actually being counted.

If there is a better way to generate random numbers within c# not based upon system time, that would solve my problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your Random static eg:

```
private static Random random = new Random();
private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

That way you will only create one Random-instance and you will keep creating new random numbers when calling RandomNumber.

Regarding the intervals, they should be set initially (E.g. class constructor)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxGPSx.Text = RandomNumber(10000, 90000).ToString();
    textBoxGPSy.Text = RandomNumber(10000, 90000).ToString();    
}
```

Hope this will help you in your quest.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you! 

Why did setting Random to static fix my problem? If System.Random generates numbers based upon system time, shouldn't the two numbers I generate be the same?  I am  somewhat of a newbie at this and don't understand why creating only one instance of Random and calling it twice at exactly the same time made the generation of numbers to differentiate. Please go into more detail if possible.

Comment: The default constructor of Random sets the seed based on the system time.  Every time a random number is generated the seed is changed to something else (based on a formula) and a random number is returned (an other formula based on the seed value.)  you can read more on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation if you want to.